# Grid elements are as wide as the Pacific Ocean

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm having an issue with a grid: for some reason the columns are about 5 times as wide as I want and no matter what I change they stay exactly the same distance apart. The HTML:

```
<div class=wrapper>
  <a href="A.html" id="A"></a>
  <a href="B.html" id="B"></a>
  <a href="C.html" id="C"></a>
</div>
```

and the (quite long) css affecting the image links in the grid:

```
.wrapper {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 3%;
    -ms-grid-columns: 100% 3% 100% 3% 100% 3% 100% 3% 100%;
    -ms-grid-rows: 100% 5% 100%;
    grid-template-columns: 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 100% 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

div.wrapper {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.wrapper a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%; 
    height: 0;
    width: 7%;
    padding-bottom: 7%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#A {
    background: url('background.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    -ms-grid-row: 1;
    -ms-grid-column: 1;
}
```

Where in this mess am I messing up?

Comment: float with grid? and why 5x 100% on the column template? .. what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to make a row of image links. I changed them down to 10% and all it did was shrink the link size :( Float is a leftover from earlier but taking it out doesn't change anything that I can see so I've been ignoring it like the slob I am

Comment: This question title is so poetic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue, I believe, is that the css `%` unit uses the parent's height and width. You have your `.wrapper` css class which defines a large space in between your links. As you mentioned in the comments of your question, if you change the `100%` to something like `10%` in the `grid-template-columns` rule, it makes the links much smaller. That is beacuse in your `.wrapper a` css class you give it a `width` and a `padding-bottom` of `7%` and it was relying on the large space to make the link larger before. If the `7%` was increased or replaced with a `vw` or `px` it would make the links the size you want.